# tmux slow to interrupt process with Ctrl-C

Tags: tmux

If I run a command with a lot of output in tmux, but decide to cancel it with Ctrl-C, there's a 10-15 second lag before it stops. However, if I do the same thing outside of tmux, it stops immediately. Why is this, and is it fixable?

In practice, this issue comes up when I'm doing `grep -R` on a large directory and my search isn't constrained enough. A workaround would be to pipe the result to `wc` first to make sure the output isn't too long, but that's just another step I'd like to avoid.

---

Notes:

- This has the same behavior in Gnome Terminal, uxterm, st, and a plain virtual terminal (e.g., ctrl-alt-f2), but the delay is less in the plain virtual terminal.
- I'm not the only one: http://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01569.html
- The delay is longer if my terminal window is larger. For a fullscreen terminal, it takes about 15 seconds to stop `grep -R` (no other arguments) in a cluttered home directory. For a 80×25 character terminal, it stops almost immediately.

Comment: I don't notice any discernable difference. I've tried `grep -R "a" ~/` (not writing to file) ... and `yes | nl | cut -f1 | head -9999999 > ~/file` then `cat ~/file` .

Comment: @Peter.O Just simply input "yes" then press Enter, your tmux is doomed.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://superuser.com/q/417556/500826)

Answer (score 11):

tmux now has the following options:

```
c0-change-interval interval
c0-change-trigger trigger
```

You can set values for these, which will make ^C and friends easier to type.  See [`man tmux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#OPTIONS):

> These two options configure a simple form of rate limiting for a pane.  If tmux sees more than *trigger* C0                     sequences that modify the screen (for example, carriage                     returns, linefeeds or backspaces) in one millisecond,                     it will stop updating the pane immediately and instead                     redraw it entirely every *interval* milliseconds.  This                     helps to prevent fast output (such as yes(1)) overwhelming the terminal.  The default is a trigger of 250                     and an interval of 100.  A trigger of zero disables the rate limiting.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, because it works.

Comment: E.g. `setw -g c0-change-trigger 10` `setw -g c0-change-interval 250` >> ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: I tried these on tmux 2.3 and they weren't recognized. It becomes totally unusable when commands spew lots of output.

Comment: Since Tmux 2.1, these options no longer exist according to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/2.6/CHANGES

    The c0-* options for rate-limiting have been removed.  Instead, a backoff approach is used.

Answer (score 9):

You can always issue `kill-pane` command from within the session. If the terminal text looks like garbage renaming the window and/or issuing `reset` should fix it.

Comment: `kill-pane` should default to `Ctrl+b`, `x`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229931/2014893

Answer (score 4):

Since `tmux` is inserting itself between the `cat` process and your terminal, it needs to read the output from `cat`, write it to the terminal , and at the same time read your input from the terminal (the ^C) and send it to the shell to interrupt the command. I'm not sure exactly what causes the delay, but it's something about how `tmux` buffers I/O between you and the shell that runs in `tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using ssh over a low-latency connection, have you tried using [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/)? Among other very nice things like input prediction as well as surviving disconnects and even a changing IP on the client side, it also specifically improves the reaction time when using Ctrl-C (by only updating the terminal contents periodically instead of sending the whole stream).

You can use `tmux` within `mosh` without any problems.

Comment: Strangely enough, this happens when I'm working locally. *mosh* looks pretty neat, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with tmux 2.3. I tried setting the c0-change-interval and c0-change-trigger options as described above but they are no longer available. Here is the git change with the new attempted solution: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/3f4ee98162cd5bb7000f93fec0e631e123b1281d

Reverting to tmux 1.8 fixed the problem for me without having to set any options.

Comment: They appear to be trying to fix this rather than using the workaround, so newer versions should get even better about the output. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/849

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a few weeks. I finally compiled from scratch, ncurses 6.4, libevent 2.1.12, and tmux 3.3a. Signal handling works as expected.

Avoid Ubuntu tmux 3.2a and take a few minutes and build from source.

If for some reason you can't compile from source try the following in your .tmux.conf:
bind-key -n C-c send-keys C-z "kill -9 %1" Enter

It will map CTRL-C into a macro of CTRL-Z (background process) and kill the background process with SIGKILL.