# Confirm a tmux option is set

Tags: terminal, tmux, ubuntu-14.04

I am having the problem described in this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/456798/tmux-slow-to-interrupt-process-with-ctrl-c) and this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/417556/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-tmux-freezing-when-lots-of-text-is-output-to-the-ter/554026#554026).

**Summary**

When I have a tmux pane that outputs a serious amount of text, tmux becomes unresponsive. All  tmux commands are ignored until the text finishes.

This was fixed in tmux by introducing the options:

```
c0-change-trigger - Number of control characters that occur in 1 ms to trigger throttling
c0-trigger-update - Time to wait between pane redraws when triggered
```

**Issue**

I am using tmux 1.8. I set the following options in my ~/.tmux.conf file:

```
# Limit character spewing
set -g c0-change-trigger  100  # default is 250 triggers/millisecond
set -g c0-change-interval 1000 # default throttle updates at 100 ms intervals
```

However, tmux still chokes on an excessive amounts of text. For example, if I go to a pane and type:

```
find /
```

The command generates lots of text and tmux doesn't let me switch panes, switch windows, detach, etc even with the c0-* options set.

I understand that you can see the options that are set by typing:

```
Ctrl-<Prefix> : show-options -g
```

In the list, I see options I set in my conf file. However, the c0-* options are not listed. So I can't verify that I have correctly set the values.

I tried intentionally misspelling the options, but I didn't see any error text. So, I don't trust that the options are being accepted.

How do I verify these options? And am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those options are window options, so you need `show-options -gw` (or `show-options -w` if they have been customized for a particular window).

---

The confusion probably comes from the fact that while `set-option -g` is ostensibly just for setting session options, it will also accept window option names (i.e. for convenience you can omit the `-w` that would otherwise be required when setting a window option).

If you care to document this distinction you might want to use `set-option -gw …` (or `set-window-option -g …`) when adjusting window options.

Comment: See `show-options [-AgHpqsvw] [-t target-pane] [option]` in the [tmux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html).